# iOS Universal link not working in background state

Tags: ios, react-native, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

In react native the iOS Universal links are working perfectly when the app is in kill/quiet state I tested it with safari but when the app is in background state it only opens the app  not working in background state my listener is not working.

```
Linking.addEventListener('url', async (link) => {
    console.log('Linking-addEventListener-link', link);
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this method is added or not into AppDelegate.m file.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(nonnull NSUserActivity *)userActivity
 restorationHandler:(nonnull void (^) (NSArray<id<UIUserActivityRestoring>> * _Nullable))restorationHandler
{
     return [RCTLinkingManager application:application
          continueUserActivity:userActivity
         restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
 }
```

Comment: Okay let me check!

Answer (score 1):

For everyone having the same issue, just make sure that
`#import <React/RCTLinkingManager.h>` is just at the top of the imports, do not add it inside any `#if #endif` import condition.

also add

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
   openURL:(NSURL *)url
   options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
{
  return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url options:options];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(nonnull NSUserActivity *)userActivity
 restorationHandler:(nonnull void (^)(NSArray<id<UIUserActivityRestoring>> * _Nullable))restorationHandler
{
 return [RCTLinkingManager application:application
                  continueUserActivity:userActivity
                    restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
}
```

just before the last `@end` inside the `@implementation AppDelegate`, hope it might help someone.

Comment: Thank you! This was doing my head in thinking I could solve it through react-native, but thought it might be something that could be fixed through the ios app, I just didn't know how.